# HTML Form Plus Button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, input

I am using an html form that submits data to a MYSQL database. I need to add a button that will increase the number in the text box by one every time pressed. My code looks like this:

```
<label for="htop">Top: </label>
<input type="button" name="decrease" value="-" /><input type="text" name="htop" value="0" />
<input type="button" name="increase" value="+" />
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you written any javascript yet? Post that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the script tag in your head element

```
<script>
function increaseBtnOnclick() {
    document.getElementById("htop").value = Number(document.getElementById("htop").value) + 1;
}
</script>

<label for="htop">Top: </label>
<input type="button" name="decrease" value="-" /><input type="text" name="htop" value="0" id="htop"/>
<input type="button" name="increase" value="+" onclick="increaseBtnOnclick()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
<input type="number">
```

Then add [a shim](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=number+input+shim) if you want to have support in browsers that don't support that part of HTML 5 yet.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this using jQuery...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var elm = $('#htop');
          function spin( vl ) {
            elm.val( parseInt( elm.val(), 10 ) + vl );
          }

          $('#increase').click( function() { spin( 1 );  } );
          $('#decrease').click( function() { spin( -1 ); } );
});
```

with

```
<label for="htop">Top: </label>
<input type="button" id="decrease" value="-" /><input type="text" id="htop" value="0" />
<input type="button" id="increase" value="+" />
```

HTH,

--hennson

Answer (score 0):

You would use one read only text input with the number, and javascript for in- and decreasing the value of the input field via 2 buttons. When the desired value is reached, the user would press a submit button for the form to be sent and saved into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript add a 'click' event to the + button:-

```
<input type="button" name="increase" value="+" onclick='document.getElementById("htop").value = document.getElementById("htop").value + 1"' />
```

This will increase the value in the field and when the form is submitted, the relevant value is returned to the server.  The '-' button needs the same but decreasing the value.  You may also wish to add a check that the value never goes below 0 or above an upper limit too.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, something like this would work.

```
$("button[name=decrease]").click(function() {
   $("input[name=htop]").val(parseInt($("input[name=htop]").val()) - 1);
});

$("button[name=increase]").click(function() {
   $("input[name=htop]").val(parseInt($("input[name=htop]").val()) + 1);
});
```